# Creating a 2D ArrayList from file

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the integers from a file that looks like this:

```
1;2;3;4;
5;6;7;8;
9;10;11;12;
```

into a 2D array list. I keep getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<>();
                myList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        try
        {
            FileReader fin = new FileReader("data.txt");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(fin);
            while(scan.hasNext())
            {
                if(scan.hasNextInt())
                {
                    myList.get(j).add(scan.nextInt());
                    i++;
                }
                else if("\\n".equals(scan.next()))
                {
                    myList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
                    j++;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Only use numbers!");
                }
            }

        }catch(Exception e){}

    System.out.println(myList.get(0).get(2));
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Do you know where the error is occurring?

Comment: I further get: "IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 0" I assume the program is not adding the integers to the arraylists, so the arraylists get out of bounds by any request.

Comment: It's probably not finding your file, but you're swallowing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is at least print the stack trace in your catch block. From the looks of it you're blowing up somewhere in there and swallowing the exception so you don't even know your program is erring out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the

```
 else if("\\n".equals(scan.next()))
            {
                myList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
                j++;
            }
```

part? I would have thought it would have been "\n". Another alternative is to maybe use your scanner and grab an entire line, then parse the line. My quick look over the code suggests the theory that that else if statement is never being executed...?

Answer (score 0):

the error occur in this line

```
 System.out.println(myList.get(0).get(2));
```

what happend that this part `myList.get(0)` return an empty list with size 0 and you want to get the third element in it by `get(2)` so IndexOutOfBoundsException been thrown, plus you must check the size before you try to get it so you dont have such an error since you code does not add integers to the list .